# Best Sellers Combination for Client’s Requirements

Tags: algorithm

I have developed a web-application where sellers put the products they are offering, price, and delivery time, and clients would prepare their own list of requirements (products and quantities) and then they would be presented with a list of sellers ordered by their total cost and/or delivery time. Noting that each “offer” might contain a combination of sellers where the combination gives the best total cost and maximum delivery time. For example:

Client needs 10 bags of beans and 15 packets of tea

Option 1: Seller ABC with 10 bags of beans for 5$ each and Seller ABCDEF with 15 packets of tea for 2$ each. Max delivery time (which is the larger of both sellers’ delivery times) 2 days.

Option 2: Seller ABC with 10 bags of beans for 5$ each and 15 packets of tea for 3$ each. Max delivery times 2 days.
Etc….

I’ve already implemented a naïve algorithm that simply checks all the permutations. But obviously this won’t scale up well at all. I need at least the name of an algorithm with or without description that can solve optimally such type of problems. I don’t really need an implementation but if there is one I hope that it depends happily on SQL for doing most of the job as I’m using a PHP 7 + MySQL combination.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't Knap Sack algorithm work for you?

Comment: [Genetic Algorithm](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/873559/Implementing-Genetic-Algorithms-in-Csharp) may fit for these kind of problem, the fitness function may need to accommodate user preferring fast delivery or cheap shipping.

Comment: @Nishit that lead me to multiple knapsack problem which then lead me to the Bin Packing Problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Martheen I wouldn't consider for now any algorithm that depends on randomized trials. I'm afraid that such algorithms might give highly unpredictable solutions. I'd certainly consider something like that in the future. Thank you